# Ubuntu 20.10: There was an error creating a child procsess. fix

Tags: command-line, 20.10

This is what happens when I launch the terminal

[image: Error upon terminal launch]

```
There was an error creating a child process
```

So I have been using the Ubuntu terminal on my Raspberry Pi 4 model B 8 GB with Ubuntu for a couple moths when Ubuntu 20.10 came out for the Pi.

But now I have a problem where I launch the terminal and it gives that message. I have gone for alternatives and tried to fix it but all the solutions were outdated or they were on a different distro.

Also the Ubuntu commands did not fix the issue because it only triggers upon a certain command.

Comment: Interesting..  can you share what terminal your trying to launch the command line and arguments /command your using?

Comment: It looks like either (1) your terminal preferences are set to open a custom command in place of the default shell, and that command is failing; or (2) your shell is failing to run because of a bad configuration (such as an error in its .rc file)

Comment: The fix I used was a different command and I can't find the rc file and drag it to the bash file in /bin/bash

Comment: I did when I tried to install wine from this guide https://www.novaspirit.com/2019/04/15/run-x86-arm/ , it diffident world and I deleted the OS and it crashed the default config

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! based on the image included in your question it looks like whatever you are attempting to run is trying to access a psuedo terminal as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean Is there a pty in /dev/ on your device? Please [edit] the output of `ls /dev | grep pty` and `ls /dev/ | grep tty`  into your post.